# analyze weekly detail reports using excel pivot tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table

We generate detail reports weekly of timesheet data posted to a cloud-based service request management application.  We export the data as CSV files.
The number of records changes each week, although the columns are the same on each weekly report.

I want to use a "standard" pivot table to analyze each week's timesheet data each week after the weekly timesheet report has bee exported.  Is it possible to import the weekly data into a standard pivot table in an Excel spreadsheet where the size of the imported timesheet CSV file will change each week?

Comment: Can there be gaps in the rows or columns?

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked and if you select the relevant /columns/ (rather than just the current cell range) before hitting Insert Pivot Table you can configure it to read the whole of $A:$D (or whatever) rather than providing a specific row bound. Hopefully that will give you what you need.

Comment: No need to select anything prior to the insertion of the pivot table - OP just needs to make sure their pivot table's data source range is setup with a dynamic range, like `Sheet1!$A:$B` as opposed to `Sheet1!$A2:$B5`. But this answer is essentially right :)

Answer (score 0):

After I figured out where I can find the function to "Change PivotTable Data Source" in Excel 365, I see that the range is already set to process all rows in the range columns (`data_tab_name!$A:$I`) so I was trying to fix a problem that didn't exist.

Comment: Rick, for future reference, you really need to post this (for which many thanks) as a comment on the first answer, not as an answer in its own right (which would need to be standalone).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information.  This was my first post and I hope to  learn accepted practices.  I wasn't sure how to post my response.